# Random Length Hair

Tags: particles, hair

I've created a grassy meadow in Blender 2.79 using a hair particle system with interpolated children. It looks great except that the hair strands are all exactly the same length. I know I can make a certain percentage of the children be a different length, but that still only gives me a mixture of 2 lengths. I really, really need a way to slightly randomize the strand lengths so the field doesn't look like it was lab-grown. There doesn't seem to be any way to do this. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Adjust the *Random Path Length* in *Particle Settings > Render > Timing* (yes, particle settings are a bit wierd) *> Random*:

[image]

Comment: Ah! Perfect! I knew it had to be there somewhere.